# After taking a picture viewDidLoad is loaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, viewdidload

In my view I have several fields, some of them are hidden. 
There is a segmentController with 2 option. 
To enable the "take a photo" button it must be set on `1`. 
So I fill the fields i see, press the segmentedController on `1` position, fill another field which was hidden and take a picture.
When I came back from the photo view, all the fields are empty and the selector is deselected (`setSelectedSegmentIndex:-1`).
If I press again this selector on `1` position, the hidden field is empty, but the UIImageView show the photo i've taken...
if I set in viewDidLoad `setSelectedSegmentIndex:1`, as I dismiss the photoView, all the fields are showed empty (again the UIImageview show the picture).
I also tried to save the contents of every field in variables and put everything back in viewDidLoad in this way

```
if (([name length] != 0) || ([price length] != 0) || (category length] != 0)) {
    //restore all the fields from those NSString variables and set segment on 1
}
```

but the app crashs.
I have this problem just if I run the app on the iPhone, not on the simulator, because the simulator takes its image right from the camera roll.

This is the code for taking photos.

```
-(IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.imgPicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    } else { 
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    int r = arc4random() % 9999;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSString *photoName = [dateNameFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    photoName = [photoName stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", r]];

    if (imagePath) {
        [imagePath release];
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", photoName]];
    [imagePath retain];

    UIImage *picture = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] retain];

// ----- CODE FOR SCALE THE IMAGE ----- //
    if (picture.size.width == 1936) {
        picture = [picture scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(480.0f, 720.0f)];
    } else {
        picture = [picture scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(720.0f, 480.0f)];
    }

    photoPreview.image =  picture;

    photoPreview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    CGRect frame = photoPreview.frame;
    if (picture.size.width == 480) {
        frame.size.width = 111.3;
        frame.size.height =167;
    } else {
        frame.size.width = 167;
        frame.size.height =111.3;
    }
    photoPreview.frame = frame;
// ----- ----- - END CODE - ----- ----- //    

    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture);
    //CGImageRelease([picture CGImage]);
    [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when using the UIImagePickerController the system usually calls a memory warning. This cause all of the views that are loaded to unload in order to free some memory.
My guess that in your case, you are not saving the state correctly and on the second call to the "viewDidLoad:" and you are unable to re-initiate the view.

you should write the viewDidLoad in a way that it can be called more than once and will still behave the same.